# How to get mysql to accept sybase database..table notation

Tags: sql, mysql, sybase, data-migration

I'm porting a sybase application to mysql and of course there's tons of sql compatibility issues, but one that I don't see an easy way out of without changing every single sql is that in sybase you can refer to a table by db..table notation, but in mysql it requires db.table.
I'm kinda on mysql's side on this one, but this is what it is.
Is there a way to get mysql to accept that syntax?

Comment: search and replace from "db.." to "db."

Comment: Tried that. There are many dbs and some of them are determined dynamically, so it's not quite that simple. The ..->. doesn't work so well either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing something like this:

```
global replace .. with " + Defs.DELIMETER + "
Then replace " + Defs.DELIMETER + ".  with ...  to take care of elipses
Then replace " + Defs.DELIMETER + "" + Defs.DELIMETER + "  with .... for those cases.
```

That got most of them.
So at least now it's easily changable.

Answer (score 1):

use a program like notepad++ that has the ability to search and replace across a whole directory of files. do a search for `..` and replace with `.`

Comment: or a command-line tool like sed which you can run all your files through if it's a big task.

Comment: Yes, I just had eclipse do that to see what would happen.
It's amazing how many ellipses and other uses for .. there are in code.